# If not is nothing in multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel

Could some one help me to find the mistake here?

```
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Select
Else
If Not rr Is Nothing Then
    rr.Select
Else
If Not rrr Is Nothing Then
    rrr.Select
Else
End If
```

Comment: What is the mistake?  Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: More context, please. What is your goal, what result does your code produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have used `If Else If` instead of `If ElseIf`  You need to either do:

```
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Select
Else
    If Not rr Is Nothing Then
        rr.Select
    Else
       If Not rrr Is Nothing Then
           rrr.Select
       Else
       End If
    End If
 End If
```

Or

```
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Select
ElseIf Not rr Is Nothing Then
    rr.Select
ElseIf Not rrr Is Nothing Then
    rrr.Select
Else
End If
```

The second one is probably better.